# Unwrap a component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is so simple I hate to ask it, but after searching the react router docs and googling around I have found nothing. I have a component that is wrapped using withRouter when it is exported:

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

I want to test this component but I am getting the following when testing:

```
<Login router={[undefined]} />
```

I usually just import my components to test them individually using enzyme's `shallow` method. Is there a way to unwrap this component so I can import it for testing?

Comment: export the unwrapped one as well `export { MyComponent }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to export that component as well:

```
export const MyComponent
```

and in your test:

```
import { MyComponent } from '../src/components/MyComponent'
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried this at first without the destructuring, with destructuring I got it working :)